# Issues running casperjs with phantomjs#2.0.0 on Mac (Yosemite)

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to run **CasperJS** having **PhantomJS#2.0.0** on a **Mac(Yosemite)**. When trying to run **CasperJS** I´m getting the following message:

```
"CasperJS needs PhantomJS v1.x

  /usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/libexec/bin/bootstrap.js:91 in __die"
```

How can I make it run? Has anyone got it working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently there is no newer version than 1.1-beta3 released which contains this check.

The simplest fix would be to open the bin/bootstrap.js file and [remove these lines](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/1.1-beta3/bin/bootstrap.js#L103-L113) or replacing the lines that are currently in the [master branch](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/15924f81fae845c9a357258fd6dafc7914b4fd4d/bin/bootstrap.js#L117-L130):

```
(function (version) {
    // required version check
    if (version.major === 1) {
        if (version.minor < 8) {
            return __die('CasperJS needs at least PhantomJS v1.8 or later.');
        }
        if (version.minor === 8 && version.patch < 1) {
            return __die('CasperJS needs at least PhantomJS v1.8.1 or later.');
        }
    } else if (version.major === 2) {
        console.log("Warning PhantomJS v2.0 not yet released. There will not be any official support for any bugs until stable version is released!");
    }
    else return __die('CasperJS needs PhantomJS v1.x or v2.x');
})(phantom.version);
```

The other option would be to [install CasperJS from git](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-from-git).

Comment: Installing from git did the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Modifying /usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/libexec/bin/bootstrap.js does not work for me. I tried but some other problems remain (Could not get casperPath and version correctly).

This issue is already fixed in master branch. Installing from git would solve this problem.

Try

```
> git clone git://github.com/n1k0/casperjs.git
> cd casperjs
> ln -sf `pwd`/bin/casperjs /usr/local/bin/casperjs
```

It fix my casperjs perfectly.

Comment: To replace binary with 1.9.x is not a option for me. I suffered from a selector bug in phantomjs 1.9.x. And that bug is not appeared in phantomjs 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem. Replacing the phantomJS executable in /usr/local/bin with that from version 1.9.8 did the trick for me.

Comment: You can even use homebrew for that. Just `brew install homebrew/versions/phantomjs198` and you're done.