# Upgrading casperjs to use phantomjs 2.0 from 1.9.8

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I read that people have found ways to get casperjs to work with phantomjs 2.0 but how could I do the upgrade? For example just swapping out phantomjs folder in /usr/.../casperjs/node_modules/phantomjs with a folder for phantomjs2 doesn't seem to do the trick. I've also made the changes in lib/bootstrap.js to handle the warnings from using 2.0.

I'm using mocha-casperjs to create my tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use PhantomJS 2, then you currently need to either

- install [CasperJS from git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28912957/1816580) (which supports PhantomJS 2) and change the fixed path in mocha-casperjs or
- remove the PhantomJS version checks in CasperJS as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28657875/1816580)

**Change the fixed path in mocha-casperjs** (in mocha-casperjs/bin/mocha-casperjs) from:

```
$mcPath/../../casperjs/bin/casperjs $mcPath/cli.js --mocha-casperjs-path=$mcPath/.. $*
```

to

```
path/to/casperjs $mcPath/cli.js --mocha-casperjs-path=$mcPath/.. $*
```

or if casperjs is in the PATH:

```
casperjs $mcPath/cli.js --mocha-casperjs-path=$mcPath/.. $*
```

**PhantomJS versions**

I suggest that you also preserve multiple versions of PhantomJS and [switch between them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30847220/1816580) if you need it. Currently there is no official PhantomJS 2 version, so you will need to build it yourself or trust zeevl who seems to have [compiled PhantomJS 2 for Linux](https://github.com/zeevl/phantomjs2):

```
npm -g install phantomjs2
```

Comment: Okay I will give this a try. I'm having a bit of trouble getting phantomjs2 install globally on my VM (some ELIFECYCLE error saying failed at the phantomjs2@2.0.0 install script 'node install.js') although it installed fine on my local machine.

Comment: I really don't. I compiled PhantomJS 2 raspberry pi myself.