# Websocket error in casperjs

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I am having a problem with casperjs where when i try to access a specific https website, i get an error along the lines of:

Error during WebSocket handshake: location mismatch: "ws://url_path != wss://url_path

I have provided the source code below. I altered urls and removed the assignment of the variable "userState" which is a property that is set on the specific webpage. I just wanted to see if anyone had an idea on how to bypass this error.

I have heard it has to do with phantomjs verson < 2.0 has this error with websockets but casperjs seemingly does not support phantomjs 2.0.

```
var casper = new require('casper').Casper({verbose: true, logLevel: "debug"});

casper.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36");

casper.start("https:www.example.com/index.html#home").then(function() {
    this.evaluate(function() {
        if(location.hash === "#home") {
            this.echo("Were on the homepage");
        } else {
            this.echo("We are not home...");
        }
    });
});

casper.thenOpen("https://www.example.com/index.html#sign-in", function() {
    this.evaluate(function() {
        if (location.hash === "#sign-in") {
            this.echo("Were on the sign in page!!!");
        } else {
            this.echo("We are not at the sign in page were: " + location.hash);
        }
    });
}); 

casper.thenEvaluate(function() {
    casper.sendKeys('#sign-in-email', "email");
    casper.sendKeys('#sign-in-password', 'password');
});

casper.thenClick('#sign-in-submit', function() {
    this.echo("We clicked the submit button");
});

casper.thenEvaluate(function() {
    // userState is an object in the context of the running web app
    if(userState === "full") {
        this.echo("WE HAVE SUCCESSFULLY SIGNED IN!");
    } else {
        this.echo("We were unable to sign in...");
    }

});
casper.run();
```

Comment: Here are some solutions about the PhantomJS version: [Issues running casperjs with phantomjs#2.0.0 on Mac (Yosemite)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28656768/1816580). You can also change the versions on the fly ([ref](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30847220/1816580)).